# Find polynomial with inequality for derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, functional-inequalities

I would like to ask a question which is related to [Find function with inequality for derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280984/find-function-with-inequality-for-derivative)

> Let $C\geq 2$ and $L>0$ be fixed. Let $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$. Does there exist a polynomial $g$ of degree $n$ such that
> \begin{equation*}
> 0 < g(0) < g(L), \qquad g'(x) > (g(L) - g(x))C, \ \ \text{for all }x \in [0,L]
> \end{equation*}
> holds at least for $n$ big enough?

In [Find function with inequality for derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280984/find-function-with-inequality-for-derivative), a function $g$ fulfilling such conditions was found, but its expression involved the exponential function. Here, I would like to know if this problem can also be solved with polynomials.

You can see already that for $n = 1$, one has $g(x) = ax + b$, $g'(x) = a$, and consequently the conditions become
\begin{equation*}
0 < b < aL+ b, \qquad (L-x)C < 1, \ \ \text{for all }x \in [0,L],
\end{equation*}
which adds a constrain on $C$ and $L$.

Comment: If $C$ and $L$ are fixed, you have a counterexample. If $C=2$ and $L=1$, in your example for $x=0$ is false that $LC=2<1$

Comment: Yes indeed, we should rather consider $n\geq 2$ at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed $L,C>0$, pick $n$ sufficient large so that $L<\frac{n}{C}$. Now define the polynomial, $$p(x):=-\left(-\frac{C}{2n}x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}+1$$ Note that $p(x)$ satisfies the points $(-n/C,0)$, $(0,1-(1/2)^{2n})$, $(n/C,1)$, $(2n/C,1-(1/2)^{2n})$, which implies that $p(x)$ has a vertex at $n/C$ (the absolute maximum of $p$), and that $p(x)$ is increasing from $(-\infty,n/C]$ (moreover, $p(x)$ has positive derivative and is in fact concave down on that same region); additionally we see that $0<p(x)< 1$ for $x\in[0,L]$. Thus $0 < -\frac{C}{2n}x+\frac{1}{2} < 1$ for $x\in[0,L]$. Additionally, we clearly see that $0<p(0)<p(L)<1$. So for any $x\in[0,L]$ we have $$\begin{array}\ 
p'(x) &=& -2n\left(-\frac{C}{2n}x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-1}\cdot\frac{-C}{2n}  \\
      &=& C\left(-\frac{C}{2n}x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-1}    \\
      &>& C\left(-\frac{C}{2n}x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}      \\
      &>& C\left(\left(-\frac{C}{2n}x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}-\left(-\frac{C}{2n}L+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}\right)  \\
      &=& C\left(p(L)-p(x)\right)  \\
\end{array}$$